# Sign convention in optic problems

Tags: optics, conventions, lenses

Note: The convention used in our physics textbook and the mentioned question is Cartesion Convention

Today in our physics test, we were given the following question:-

A mirror has focal length **20 cm** and produces an image 1/3 the size of an object. Find the **object distance**

The question is pretty straightforward but the problem me and my classmates  faced was whether to take the focal length as +ve or -ve or both.

What I used to think was that if a distance was given without a sign we will **assume it to be positive**.
And hence, in my solution I took the given mirror to be convex (Cartesian Convention)

But my friend said that if focal length is given without a sign it refers to the magnitude of focal length.Thus, they solved the problem for both concave and convex mirrors.

**In the nutshell**, my question is **Is 20cm the same as +20 cm or not?**

I feel that my question is not much of a conceptual question but one regarding the **convention** of assigning signs to distances.Also I couldn't refer to my textbook as in all problems the mirror was specified as convex or concave beforehand.

Pls help. Also could someone suggest some text which I can refer to regarding this question.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Does the same concern apply to the sign of the magnification?

Comment: Not really, I am more concerned about sign of focal length

Answer (score 1):

As given in the question, the mirror tends to form an image of **magnification 1/3**, through this we can infer that the image formed is **diminished**(smaller than the size of the object).
A concave mirror has the capability of producing a diminished image when the object is either placed at **infinity(very distant)** or is placed **beyond the** **center of curvature**. Similarly, a convex mirror also has the potential of producing a diminished image **regardless of the position of the object** from the mirror and therefore we would have to take both the cases while solving this question:

1. *CASE 1:* When the mirror is considered to be a **concave mirror** then the focal length taken would be **negative.**
2. *CASE 2:* When the mirror is considered to be a **convex mirror** then the focal length taken would be **positive.**

Answer (score -1):

Given that you have a sign convention I would have taken the focal length of the mirror to be $+20\, \rm cm$ and assumed that there was no ambiguity for the sign of the relative magnitudes $\frac 13$ as the word magnification was not used.

However with the focal length as $+20\, \rm cm$ (and also $-20\, \rm cm$) there is another answer.

[image]

The top ray diagram is the most obvious but you could reverse the direction of the rays in the bottom diagram and the start with a virtual object which is three times the size of the real image.